# Show that $\sin(3x)$ is equivalent to $3\sin(x)\cos^2(x)-\sin^3(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> The expression $\sin(3x)$ is equivalent to:
>
> A. ...

My book states the right answer is B which is $3\sin(x)\cos^2(x)-\sin^3(x)$.

I tried:

$$\sin(x)\cos(2x)+\cos(x)\sin(2x) = \\
\sin(x)(2\cos^2(x)-1)+\cos(x)\cdot2\sin(x)\cos(x) = \\
2\cdot\sin(x)\cos(x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)+\cos(x)2\sin(x)\cos(x) = \\
\sin(x)(2\cos^2(x)-1+2\cos^2(x)) = \\
\sin(x)(4\cos^2(x)-1) = \\
4\cos^2(x)\sin(x)-\sin(x) = ???$$

What do I do next?

Comment: Can you use differentiation/integration?

Comment: Just so you know a better version of the double angle formula for cosine is $\cos^2{x} - \sin^2{x} = \cos{2x}$ since $\cos{2x} = \cos{x+x} = \cos{x}\cos{x} - \sin{x}\sin{x}$. This is because $\cos{A \pm B} = \cos{A}\cos{B} \mp \sin{A}\sin{B}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin(3x) = \sin(x+2x)$$

$$= \sin(x) \cos(2x) + \sin(2x) \cos(x)$$

$$ = \sin(x) ( \cos^2(x) - \sin^2 (x)) + \cos(x) (2 \sin(x) \cos(x)) $$

$$= 3 \sin(x) \cos^2 (x) - \sin^3 (x )$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that \begin{equation}\begin{split}\sin(3x)  &= 4\cos^2 x \sin x - \sin x\\&= 3\sin x \cos^2 x +(\sin x \cos^2x -\sin x )\\&=3\sin x \cos^2 x + \sin x\cdot( \cos^2x - 1)\\&= 3\sin x \cos^2 x -\sin^3 x \end{split}\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Almost there (from your 5th line):
$$
\sin x (4\cos^2 x - 1) = \sin x (3\cos^2 x + \cos^2 x  - 1)
$$
$$
= \sin x (3\cos^2 x + (1-\sin^2 x)  - 1) = 3\sin x\cos^2 x-\sin^3x.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Also it can be proved using complex numbers.

$(\cos x+i\sin x)^3=\cos 3x+i\sin 3x $ (Moivre's formula)

$(\cos x+i\sin x)^3=(\cos^3x-3\cos x\sin^2x)+i(3\cos^2 x\sin x-\sin^3x)$ (binom)

Comparing these two formulas, we obtain

$\cos 3x=\cos^3x-3\cos x\sin^2x=\cos^3x-3\cos x(1-\cos^2x)=\ldots$

$\sin 3x =3\cos^2 x\sin x-\sin^3x=\ldots$